# Tex Live Updater suddenly broke

Tags: errors, texlive, tex-core, kpathsea

I have used Tex Live GUI to update packages. Suddenly it does not work. When I run TLShell TeX Live Manager, I get the following message:

```
C:/texlive/2022
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/texmf-local/ls-r: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/2022/texmf-config/ls-r: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
  while executing
"exec kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFROOT"
  invoked from within
"set::instroot [exec kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFROOT]"
  (file "C:\texlive\2022\texmf-dist\scripttlshell\tlshell.tcl" line 31)
```

Until yesterday night everything was fine. I updated some packages without errors and there was no sign of failure at all. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: try from the command line:  `tlmgr --all --self update`

Comment: sounds similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/660247/dozens-of-errors-when-updating-tex-live-from-command-line-are-they-concerning