# Dozens of errors when updating TeX Live from command line: are they concerning?

Tags: pdftex, texlive, windows, tlmgr, texlive2022

I ran this line of code on the command line to update tlmgr itself and all packages.

```
tlmgr update --self --all
```

While the packages successfully updated, there was a significant amount of warning and error messages. What should I do to fix the errors?

```
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/texmf-local/ls-r: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/2022/texmf-config/ls-r: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/texmf-local/ls-r: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/2022/texmf-config/ls-r: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/texmf-local/ls-r: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/2022/texmf-config/ls-r: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/texmf-local/ls-r: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/2022/texmf-config/ls-r: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/texmf-local/ls-r: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/2022/texmf-config/ls-r: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/texmf-local/ls-r: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/2022/texmf-config/ls-r: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
tlmgr.pl: package repositories
        main = https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
        tlcontrib = http://contrib.texlive.info/current (not verified: gpg unavailable)
For more about verification, see https://texlive.info/verification.html.
tlmgr.pl: saving backups to C:/texlive/2022/tlpkg/backups
tlmgr.pl: no self-updates for tlmgr available
[ 1/14, ??:??/??:??] update: abntexto [140k] (64513 -> 64561@main) ... done
[ 2/14, 00:05/17:53] update: arimo [2866k] (42880 -> 64548@main) ... done
[ 3/14, 00:12/01:59] update: bithesis [876k] (64398 -> 64554@main) ... done
[ 4/14, 00:21/02:42] update: caladea [427k] (34991 -> 64549@main) ... done
[ 5/14, 00:28/03:14] update: cinzel [560k] (54512 -> 64550@main) ... done
[ 6/14, 00:39/03:59] update: coelacanth [6740k] (54736 -> 64558@main) ... done
[ 7/14, 00:48/02:03] update: colorframed [34k] (64491 -> 64551@main) ... done
[ 8/14, 00:57/02:26] update: crimson [1385k] (54512 -> 64559@main) ... done
[ 9/14, 01:04/02:27] update: graphics-pln [11k] (64532 -> 64553@main) ... done
[10/14, 01:08/02:36] update: install-latex-guide-zh-cn [789k] (64257 -> 64560@main) ... done
[11/14, 01:14/02:40] update: l3backend [916k] (64252 -> 64552@main) ... done
[12/14, 01:23/02:48] update: l3kernel [12392k] (64251 -> 64552@main) ... done
[13/14, 02:42/02:58] update: tex4ht [2296k] (64534 -> 64562@main) ... done
[14/14, 03:04/03:07] update: texlive-scripts [523k] (64536 -> 64557@main) ... warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/texmf-local/ls-r: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/2022/texmf-config/ls-r: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
done
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
running mtxrun --generate ...
done running mtxrun --generate.
running updmap-sys ...
done running updmap-sys.
regenerating fmtutil.cnf in C:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist
running fmtutil-sys --byfmt xelatex --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\JnBwloHehb\wgUTvwoIWK ...
  OK: xelatex.fmt/xetex
running fmtutil-sys --byfmt eplain --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\JnBwloHehb\wgUTvwoIWK ...
  OK: xelatex.fmt/xetex eplain.fmt/pdftex
running fmtutil-sys --byfmt uplatex --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\JnBwloHehb\wgUTvwoIWK ...
  OK: xelatex.fmt/xetex eplain.fmt/pdftex uplatex.fmt/euptex
running fmtutil-sys --byfmt pdfjadetex --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\JnBwloHehb\wgUTvwoIWK ...
  OK: xelatex.fmt/xetex eplain.fmt/pdftex uplatex.fmt/euptex pdfjadetex.fmt/pdftex
running fmtutil-sys --byfmt mllatex --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\JnBwloHehb\wgUTvwoIWK ...
  OK: xelatex.fmt/xetex eplain.fmt/pdftex uplatex.fmt/euptex pdfjadetex.fmt/pdftex mllatex.fmt/pdftex
running fmtutil-sys --byfmt latex --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\JnBwloHehb\wgUTvwoIWK ...
  OK: xelatex.fmt/xetex eplain.fmt/pdftex uplatex.fmt/euptex pdfjadetex.fmt/pdftex mllatex.fmt/pdftex latex.fmt/pdftex
running fmtutil-sys --byfmt devlatex --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\JnBwloHehb\wgUTvwoIWK ...

tlmgr.pl: fmtutil-sys --byfmt devlatex --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\JnBwloHehb\wgUTvwoIWK failed (status 1), output:
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil:   c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   c:/texlive/2022/texmf-config/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [INFO]: writing formats under c:/texlive/2022/texmf-var/web2c
fmtutil [INFO]: --- remaking devlatex with pdftex-dev
fmtutil [ERROR]: not building devlatex due to missing engine: pdftex-dev
fmtutil [INFO]: disabled formats: 5
fmtutil [INFO]: not selected formats: 56
fmtutil [INFO]: failed to build: 1 (pdftex-dev/devlatex)
fmtutil [INFO]: total formats: 62
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 1
C:\texlive\2022\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 1:
perl.exe c:\texlive\2022\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\fmtutil.pl  --sys --byfmt devlatex --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\JnBwloHehb\wgUTvwoIWK
  OK: xelatex.fmt/xetex eplain.fmt/pdftex uplatex.fmt/euptex pdfjadetex.fmt/pdftex mllatex.fmt/pdftex latex.fmt/pdftex
  ERROR: devlatex.fmt/pdftex-dev
running fmtutil-sys --byfmt platex-dev --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\JnBwloHehb\wgUTvwoIWK ...
  OK: xelatex.fmt/xetex eplain.fmt/pdftex uplatex.fmt/euptex pdfjadetex.fmt/pdftex mllatex.fmt/pdftex latex.fmt/pdftex platex-dev.fmt/eptex
  ERROR: devlatex.fmt/pdftex-dev
running fmtutil-sys --byfmt xmltex --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\JnBwloHehb\wgUTvwoIWK ...
  OK: xelatex.fmt/xetex eplain.fmt/pdftex uplatex.fmt/euptex pdfjadetex.fmt/pdftex mllatex.fmt/pdftex latex.fmt/pdftex platex-dev.fmt/eptex xmltex.fmt/pdftex
  ERROR: devlatex.fmt/pdftex-dev
running fmtutil-sys --byfmt platex --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\JnBwloHehb\wgUTvwoIWK ...
  OK: xelatex.fmt/xetex eplain.fmt/pdftex uplatex.fmt/euptex pdfjadetex.fmt/pdftex mllatex.fmt/pdftex latex.fmt/pdftex platex-dev.fmt/eptex xmltex.fmt/pdftex platex.fmt/eptex
  ERROR: devlatex.fmt/pdftex-dev
running fmtutil-sys --byfmt pdflatex --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\JnBwloHehb\wgUTvwoIWK ...
  OK: xelatex.fmt/xetex eplain.fmt/pdftex uplatex.fmt/euptex pdfjadetex.fmt/pdftex mllatex.fmt/pdftex latex.fmt/pdftex platex-dev.fmt/eptex xmltex.fmt/pdftex platex.fmt/eptex pdflatex.fmt/pdftex
  ERROR: devlatex.fmt/pdftex-dev
running fmtutil-sys --byfmt dvilualatex --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\JnBwloHehb\wgUTvwoIWK ...
  OK: xelatex.fmt/xetex eplain.fmt/pdftex uplatex.fmt/euptex pdfjadetex.fmt/pdftex mllatex.fmt/pdftex latex.fmt/pdftex platex-dev.fmt/eptex xmltex.fmt/pdftex platex.fmt/eptex pdflatex.fmt/pdftex dvilualatex.fmt/luatex
  ERROR: devlatex.fmt/pdftex-dev
running fmtutil-sys --byfmt latex-dev --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\JnBwloHehb\wgUTvwoIWK ...
  OK: xelatex.fmt/xetex eplain.fmt/pdftex uplatex.fmt/euptex pdfjadetex.fmt/pdftex mllatex.fmt/pdftex latex.fmt/pdftex platex-dev.fmt/eptex xmltex.fmt/pdftex platex.fmt/eptex pdflatex.fmt/pdftex dvilualatex.fmt/luatex latex-dev.fmt/pdftex
  ERROR: devlatex.fmt/pdftex-dev
running fmtutil-sys --byfmt cslatex --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\JnBwloHehb\wgUTvwoIWK ...
  OK: xelatex.fmt/xetex eplain.fmt/pdftex uplatex.fmt/euptex pdfjadetex.fmt/pdftex mllatex.fmt/pdftex latex.fmt/pdftex platex-dev.fmt/eptex xmltex.fmt/pdftex platex.fmt/eptex pdflatex.fmt/pdftex dvilualatex.fmt/luatex latex-dev.fmt/pdftex cslatex.fmt/pdftex
  ERROR: devlatex.fmt/pdftex-dev
running fmtutil-sys --byfmt lualatex-dev --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\JnBwloHehb\wgUTvwoIWK ...
  OK: xelatex.fmt/xetex eplain.fmt/pdftex uplatex.fmt/euptex pdfjadetex.fmt/pdftex mllatex.fmt/pdftex latex.fmt/pdftex platex-dev.fmt/eptex xmltex.fmt/pdftex platex.fmt/eptex pdflatex.fmt/pdftex dvilualatex.fmt/luatex latex-dev.fmt/pdftex cslatex.fmt/pdftex lualatex-dev.fmt/luahbtex
  ERROR: devlatex.fmt/pdftex-dev
running fmtutil-sys --byfmt devpdflatex --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\JnBwloHehb\wgUTvwoIWK ...

tlmgr.pl: fmtutil-sys --byfmt devpdflatex --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\JnBwloHehb\wgUTvwoIWK failed (status 1), output:
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil:   c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   c:/texlive/2022/texmf-config/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [INFO]: writing formats under c:/texlive/2022/texmf-var/web2c
fmtutil [INFO]: --- remaking devpdflatex with pdftex-dev
fmtutil [ERROR]: not building devpdflatex due to missing engine: pdftex-dev
fmtutil [INFO]: disabled formats: 5
fmtutil [INFO]: not selected formats: 56
fmtutil [INFO]: failed to build: 1 (pdftex-dev/devpdflatex)
fmtutil [INFO]: total formats: 62
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 1
C:\texlive\2022\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 1:
perl.exe c:\texlive\2022\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\fmtutil.pl  --sys --byfmt devpdflatex --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\JnBwloHehb\wgUTvwoIWK
  OK: xelatex.fmt/xetex eplain.fmt/pdftex uplatex.fmt/euptex pdfjadetex.fmt/pdftex mllatex.fmt/pdftex latex.fmt/pdftex platex-dev.fmt/eptex xmltex.fmt/pdftex platex.fmt/eptex pdflatex.fmt/pdftex dvilualatex.fmt/luatex latex-dev.fmt/pdftex cslatex.fmt/pdftex lualatex-dev.fmt/luahbtex
  ERROR: devlatex.fmt/pdftex-dev devpdflatex.fmt/pdftex-dev
running fmtutil-sys --byfmt dvilualatex-dev --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\JnBwloHehb\wgUTvwoIWK ...
  OK: xelatex.fmt/xetex eplain.fmt/pdftex uplatex.fmt/euptex pdfjadetex.fmt/pdftex mllatex.fmt/pdftex latex.fmt/pdftex platex-dev.fmt/eptex xmltex.fmt/pdftex platex.fmt/eptex pdflatex.fmt/pdftex dvilualatex.fmt/luatex latex-dev.fmt/pdftex cslatex.fmt/pdftex lualatex-dev.fmt/luahbtex dvilualatex-dev.fmt/luatex
  ERROR: devlatex.fmt/pdftex-dev devpdflatex.fmt/pdftex-dev
running fmtutil-sys --byfmt jadetex --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\JnBwloHehb\wgUTvwoIWK ...
  OK: xelatex.fmt/xetex eplain.fmt/pdftex uplatex.fmt/euptex pdfjadetex.fmt/pdftex mllatex.fmt/pdftex latex.fmt/pdftex platex-dev.fmt/eptex xmltex.fmt/pdftex platex.fmt/eptex pdflatex.fmt/pdftex dvilualatex.fmt/luatex latex-dev.fmt/pdftex cslatex.fmt/pdftex lualatex-dev.fmt/luahbtex dvilualatex-dev.fmt/luatex jadetex.fmt/pdftex
  ERROR: devlatex.fmt/pdftex-dev devpdflatex.fmt/pdftex-dev
running fmtutil-sys --byfmt uplatex-dev --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\JnBwloHehb\wgUTvwoIWK ...
  OK: xelatex.fmt/xetex eplain.fmt/pdftex uplatex.fmt/euptex pdfjadetex.fmt/pdftex mllatex.fmt/pdftex latex.fmt/pdftex platex-dev.fmt/eptex xmltex.fmt/pdftex platex.fmt/eptex pdflatex.fmt/pdftex dvilualatex.fmt/luatex latex-dev.fmt/pdftex cslatex.fmt/pdftex lualatex-dev.fmt/luahbtex dvilualatex-dev.fmt/luatex jadetex.fmt/pdftex uplatex-dev.fmt/euptex
  ERROR: devlatex.fmt/pdftex-dev devpdflatex.fmt/pdftex-dev
running fmtutil-sys --byfmt pdfxmltex --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\JnBwloHehb\wgUTvwoIWK ...
  OK: xelatex.fmt/xetex eplain.fmt/pdftex uplatex.fmt/euptex pdfjadetex.fmt/pdftex mllatex.fmt/pdftex latex.fmt/pdftex platex-dev.fmt/eptex xmltex.fmt/pdftex platex.fmt/eptex pdflatex.fmt/pdftex dvilualatex.fmt/luatex latex-dev.fmt/pdftex cslatex.fmt/pdftex lualatex-dev.fmt/luahbtex dvilualatex-dev.fmt/luatex jadetex.fmt/pdftex uplatex-dev.fmt/euptex pdfxmltex.fmt/pdftex
  ERROR: devlatex.fmt/pdftex-dev devpdflatex.fmt/pdftex-dev
running fmtutil-sys --byfmt xelatex-dev --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\JnBwloHehb\wgUTvwoIWK ...
  OK: xelatex.fmt/xetex eplain.fmt/pdftex uplatex.fmt/euptex pdfjadetex.fmt/pdftex mllatex.fmt/pdftex latex.fmt/pdftex platex-dev.fmt/eptex xmltex.fmt/pdftex platex.fmt/eptex pdflatex.fmt/pdftex dvilualatex.fmt/luatex latex-dev.fmt/pdftex cslatex.fmt/pdftex lualatex-dev.fmt/luahbtex dvilualatex-dev.fmt/luatex jadetex.fmt/pdftex uplatex-dev.fmt/euptex pdfxmltex.fmt/pdftex xelatex-dev.fmt/xetex
  ERROR: devlatex.fmt/pdftex-dev devpdflatex.fmt/pdftex-dev
running fmtutil-sys --byfmt pdfcslatex --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\JnBwloHehb\wgUTvwoIWK ...
  OK: xelatex.fmt/xetex eplain.fmt/pdftex uplatex.fmt/euptex pdfjadetex.fmt/pdftex mllatex.fmt/pdftex latex.fmt/pdftex platex-dev.fmt/eptex xmltex.fmt/pdftex platex.fmt/eptex pdflatex.fmt/pdftex dvilualatex.fmt/luatex latex-dev.fmt/pdftex cslatex.fmt/pdftex lualatex-dev.fmt/luahbtex dvilualatex-dev.fmt/luatex jadetex.fmt/pdftex uplatex-dev.fmt/euptex pdfxmltex.fmt/pdftex xelatex-dev.fmt/xetex pdfcslatex.fmt/pdftex
  ERROR: devlatex.fmt/pdftex-dev devpdflatex.fmt/pdftex-dev
running fmtutil-sys --byfmt lualatex --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\JnBwloHehb\wgUTvwoIWK ...
  OK: xelatex.fmt/xetex eplain.fmt/pdftex uplatex.fmt/euptex pdfjadetex.fmt/pdftex mllatex.fmt/pdftex latex.fmt/pdftex platex-dev.fmt/eptex xmltex.fmt/pdftex platex.fmt/eptex pdflatex.fmt/pdftex dvilualatex.fmt/luatex latex-dev.fmt/pdftex cslatex.fmt/pdftex lualatex-dev.fmt/luahbtex dvilualatex-dev.fmt/luatex jadetex.fmt/pdftex uplatex-dev.fmt/euptex pdfxmltex.fmt/pdftex xelatex-dev.fmt/xetex pdfcslatex.fmt/pdftex lualatex.fmt/luahbtex
  ERROR: devlatex.fmt/pdftex-dev devpdflatex.fmt/pdftex-dev
running fmtutil-sys --byfmt pdflatex-dev --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\JnBwloHehb\wgUTvwoIWK ...
  OK: xelatex.fmt/xetex eplain.fmt/pdftex uplatex.fmt/euptex pdfjadetex.fmt/pdftex mllatex.fmt/pdftex latex.fmt/pdftex platex-dev.fmt/eptex xmltex.fmt/pdftex platex.fmt/eptex pdflatex.fmt/pdftex dvilualatex.fmt/luatex latex-dev.fmt/pdftex cslatex.fmt/pdftex lualatex-dev.fmt/luahbtex dvilualatex-dev.fmt/luatex jadetex.fmt/pdftex uplatex-dev.fmt/euptex pdfxmltex.fmt/pdftex xelatex-dev.fmt/xetex pdfcslatex.fmt/pdftex lualatex.fmt/luahbtex pdflatex-dev.fmt/pdftex
  ERROR: devlatex.fmt/pdftex-dev devpdflatex.fmt/pdftex-dev
tlmgr.pl: package log updated: C:/texlive/2022/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
tlmgr.pl: command log updated: C:/texlive/2022/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr-commands.log
tlmgr.pl: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

Comment: sounds related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/660203/tex-live-updater-suddenly-broke

Comment: looks like a problem with  write permission to the directory/files.